# is ERC-20 unalterable?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

Taking this ERC-20 Contract standar structure:

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol

**Its it unalterable by developer?**

Could I change the name of contract (without ERC20)?
Could I change the name os structure of mappings variables?
Could I change the events structure? Could I remove the events? Could I change the events name?

What is the EVM real standar and unalterable ERC-20 for proper functioning of a token?

Comment: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20

Comment: Thnks! I know it. My question is if I can change the variable names. For example, instead "totalSupply", write "myTotalSupply". Or EVM needs this fixed names?

Comment: @JTConsulta You can change the name of the `_totalSupply` variable but not the name of the `totalSupply` function which is part of the EIP.

Comment: Ok, i understand. Then, my contract needs to respect function names of eip-20, but i supposed that i can change the mapping names that is not declared in eip-20. Its correct?